# Wordpress woocommerce my-account doesn't show edit address placeholder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need help adding the "html placeholder" for a link in the woocommerce my-account page. Specifically the "edit-adress" which in my language is called "verzend- factuurgegevens" does not show in the list but the link is there and so is the list item.

I will add a screenshot of the source code and the page. Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sync. the translation file via LoCo translate made the link text appear but it's still not in the right language...